# Two independent sample proportion test

Tags: statistics, sas

This question is pretty simple (I hope). I am working my way through some introductory to SAS material and cannot find the proper way of running a two sample proportion test of location.

`proc freq data;
tables / binomial (p=...)
run;`

requires a known proportion (i.e. testing against a known value). I'd like to compare two samples of categorical variables with null hypothesis p1 = p2 and p1 < p2.

Data resembles:

```
V1  Yes
V1  No
V2  Yes
V2  No
```

For many lines. I need to compare the proportion of Yes's and No's between the two populations (V1 and V2). Can someone point me towards the correct procedure? Google search has left me spinning.

Thanks.

Comment: This is sort of in a gray area, but it's probably a slightly better question for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) since it's a question of which stat test to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/0 and 1/0 seems like a Chi Squared test.

```
data for_test;
do _t = 1 to 20;
 x1 = ifn(ranuni(7)<0.5,1,0);
 x2 = ifn(ranuni(7)<0.5,1,0);
 output;
end;
run;

proc freq data=for_test;
tables x1*x2/chisq;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

The chi square test for quality of proportion. Here the use case of p1 < p2  is still pending. It is possible to do the test for p1 < p2  using chi